# NextJS 13 overwrites my favicon with its default one

Tags: next.js, next.js13

My icon is located in /public/favicon.ico

In my Layout.jsx, I have this

```
export const metadata = {
  icons: {
    icon: '/favicon.ico',
  }
}
```

It does render it correctly, and the path is working fine, however the default one overwrites it...

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" href="/_next/static/media/metadata/favicon.603d046c.ico" type="image/x-icon" sizes="any">
```

Is there a way to ask next to not use the default favicon ?

Edit: I'm on NextJS 13.2

Comment: Are you using the app folder?

Comment: Yes @YoussoufOumar

Comment: do you still have `head.jsx` file?

Answer (score 1):

> Note: We recommend using the file-based Metadata API for icons where possible.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#icons

> File-based metadata has the higher priority and will override any config-based metadata.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata

Check your app folder, a favicon.ico should be here, so the favicon you declared in metadata does not work as expected.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons

Replace the default `favicon.ico` in the root `app` folder with a different one works, tested with `next@13.4.1`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata#app-icons) and testing. All you need to do is add the icon file to the root segment of the app directory to set an icon for your application. NextJS 13 will automatically set it for you.

Just add a favicon.ico, icon.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|svg), or apple-icon.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg) file to the root segment.

Note: You can set multiple icons for your application by adding a number suffix to the file name. For example, icon1.(jpg|tsx), icon2.(jpg|tsx), etc. Numbered files will sort lexically.

Comment: why would you need multiple icons ?

Comment: It will be same icon with different sizes. Eg: icon1.png for 16x16, icon2.png for 32x32, etc. Which will be auto detected across different devices and browser types.

You can read this article for more details: https://mailchimp.com/resources/favicon-size/

Answer (score 0):

In **Next V13.4.0 and above** you need to **rename** your favicon to .(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|svg), and apple icon to apple-icon.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg) like so:

```
export const metadata = {
  icons: {
    icon: './icon.ico',
    shortcut: './icon.ico',
    apple: './apple-icon.png',
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your icon was placed at `/public/favicon.ico`, while default Next's icon was placed at `/app/favicon.ico`, which is the correct location.

Note: if you want to use other named favicon or have a dynamic one, you should remove all the default Next icons (favicon.ico, icon.png, icon.svg, apple-icon.png...), otherwise they will still be loaded.

Then, you'll be able to load your custom favicon:

```
export const metadata = {
  icons: {
    icon: '/custom.ico',
  }
}
```