# NextJs 13 Beta: How to add multiple sizes of favicons using new Metadata api? Is it possible to add site manifest here as well?

Tags: next.js, metadata, manifest, favicon, next.js13

I am looking to add multiple browser-specific favicons, but I get ts( 1117 ) stating 'An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.'

I understand this, but the type interface also will not let me name 'icon' anything else. For instance, 'apple-touch-icon: ' or 'icon2' does not work.

Also if i place a favicon directly in the next/static/metadata folder, it works and displays correctly when testing in my browser without any need to state explicitly in the code...

Is this a case for using dynamic metadata? Should I use conditional logic to render according to the identified device? I feel like that would be overcomplicating it! Sorry for my lack of understanding as I am new to web development.

Also, is there anyway to add the manifest using this new metadata API? I don't see anything other than 'title: ', 'description: ', and 'icons: '.

Here is what I have at the top of my layout.tsx file:

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'Welcome',
  icons: {
    // icon: "/_next/static/media/metadata/apple-touch-icon.png",
    icon: "/_next/static/media/metadata/favicon-32x32.png",
    // icon: "/_next/static/media/metadata/favicon-16x16.png",
  },
// manifest: "/site.webmanifest",
}
;
```

Comment: I have already answered to this question, you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76135234/8111548)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually define the icon sizes in your client-side code and then use the same sizes when you create your custom object records with the metadata API.

```
const getFaviconUrls = async () => {
  const isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
  const isAndroid = /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
  const isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);

  const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

  let iconSizes = [];

  if (isIOS) {
    iconSizes = [
      57,
      60,
      72,
      76,
      114,
      120,
      180
    ];
  } else if (isAndroid && isChrome) {
    iconSizes = [
      36,
      48,
      72,
      96,
      144,
      192,
      512
    ];
  } else {
    iconSizes = [32];
  }

  // Retrieve the CustomObject records from Salesforce
  const iconRecords = await conn.metadata.read('CustomObject', iconSizes.map(size => `Icon_${size}`));

  // Map the icon records to their filenames
  const iconFilenames = iconRecords.records.map(record => `/path/to/${record.Filename__c}`);

  return iconFilenames;
};
```

Rename "Icon_${size}" to what your icons are called. "apple-touch-icon-${size}" or "android-chrome-${size}".

Comment: Thank you so much, friend. I will try this. Any chance you can take a look at my most recent post? I am having an issue importing a lottie .json animation into a component also in Next13 Beta.

Comment: preciate it @Jobajuba! haven't had any help on it yet I think because my account is too new I don't have rep